# How to get substring from a part of string while searching from the back

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string with code from another JAVA class and i am extracting Doc comments. I have a string with the following content:

```
"public static String[] scanread() throws Exception{"
```

I need to get the "scanread()" how can i extract that? I was hoping something that looks for ")" and continues reading right to left until it reaches white space, then extracts it. I am not too sure how would i do that.
Also with this i am worried if there is a space between "scanread" and "()" that might not work.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: With a Java code parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex along with Pattern and Matcher classes.

```
"\\S+\\)"
```

OR

```
"\\S+\\s*\\(\\)"
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters , so this matches all the non-space characters which exists before to `)` bracket, including the bracket.

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/qO3uD3/2)

```
String s = "public static String[] scanread() throws Exception{";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\)").matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
scanread()
```

Comment: This seems to work so far, but it doesn't work if there is a whitespace between scanread and (). Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: or `"\\S+\\s*\\([^()]*\\)"`

Comment: This has been a great help! If i may ask so, lets assume there is random stuff inside the ( ) arguments and such. Is there a way to select that too as it can have any number of spaces or any number/types of characters? for example: "scanread(String a, int z, String[] b)"

Comment: `\\(([^)]*)\\)` use this regex and get the part you want from group index 1.